# PowerShell RemoteException incosistency when run via remote runspace

Tags: powershell, jenkins, powershell-remoting

I've got this demo-script, which I put into a Jenkins job:

```bsh
Write-Host "##############################################"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

Write-Host "ErrorActionPreference: $ErrorActionPreference"
Write-Host "whoami: $(whoami)"
$PSVersionTable | Format-Table

try {
 cmd /c "comanddoesnotexist c:/foo c:/bar"
} catch {
 Write-Host "### Exception! ###"
}

Write-Host "################### TRACE ###########################"

Trace-Command -Name errorrecord  -Expression { cmd /c "comanddoesnotexist c:/foo c:/bar" }  -PSHost

Write-Host "##############################################"
```

When I run it locally, I get the following result:

```
##############################################
ErrorActionPreference: Stop
whoami: td\builder

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.1
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1


Der Befehl "comanddoesnotexist" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
################### TRACE ###########################
Der Befehl "comanddoesnotexist" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
##############################################
```

however, when I run the exact same thing via Jenkins, I do get the following:

```
[PowerShell_DummyChecks] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\BUILDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins5194440861464562005.ps1'"
##############################################
ErrorActionPreference: Stop
whoami: td\builder

Name                           Value                                                                                   
----                           -----                                                                                   
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.1                                                                             
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                 
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                 
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.1                                                                            
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                         
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                     
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                     
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                 


### Exception! ###
################### TRACE ###########################
cmd : Der Befehl "comanddoesnotexist" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
In C:\Users\builder\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins5194440861464562005.ps1:16 Zeichen:48
+ ... cord  -Expression { cmd /c "comanddoesnotexist c:/foo c:/bar" }  -PSH ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Der Befehl "com...eschrieben oder:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

where does this 'RemoteException' come from - why is it being caught?
note that the Jenkins-service is being executed with the same account as when run locally.

to make it even worse, this issue only seems to exist with the above stated combination of Win10 + PowerShell, when I run the same job on another (older) server, I get the following (expected) result:

```
[PowerShell_DummyChecks] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\BUILDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins5640455886657276493.ps1'"
##############################################
ErrorActionPreference: Stop
whoami: td\builder

Name                           Value                                                                                   
----                           -----                                                                                   
PSVersion                      5.1.14393.3053                                                                          
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                 
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                 
BuildVersion                   10.0.14393.3053                                                                         
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                         
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                     
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                     
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                 


Der Befehl "comanddoesnotexist" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
################### TRACE ###########################
Der Befehl "comanddoesnotexist" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
##############################################
Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

and now, to add yet another layer of crazy:

> when I run this script *remotely* via Enter-PSSession, it always fails with the "weird" behavior as on the new server. (also on the old hosts)

has anybody got a clue what's going on here?

Comment: Normally PowerShell convert stderr output from native applications to PowerShell's own error objects. But in some cases (when PowerShell host run locally, own console window and error stream for native application is not redirected in PowerShell) it patch native application stderr to PowerShell host stderr, bypassing PowerShell engine entirely, and thus giving up ability to react to stderr from native application.

Comment: @PetSerAl - thb I don't quite get it - can you point to some documentation? is there a way to force one method or the other?

Comment: I am not sure if such documentation exists. I can point to [source](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master@{2019-07-23}/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/NativeCommandProcessor.cs#L1176-L1294) which is responsible to the decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: all of this is only tested/verified on Windows PowerShell 5.1

A 'RemoteException' is generated from STDERR when PowerShell runs without attached Console. (Which is (also) the case in a PS remote session).
When powershell "sees" a Console (i.e. CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or no specific flags), it [will not generate any exception or error](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3996#issuecomment-308242927), instead it will 
just pipe STDERR ouput from a child process through to its very own STDERR stream. This STDERR output will in turn show up on the Console window without 
any red highligthing or PS exceptions.

*It looks as if you're running into trouble when running from a process that has been invoked with 'CREATE_NO_WINDOW' or 'DETACHED_PROCESS' flags.*

**In Windows 10 1809:**
When running powershell.exe without Console, just [like Jenkins does it](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/f0c5108184a75e589493afe6d54879b5c4b7ed54/core/src/main/java/hudson/Launcher.java#L1385) (Java Runtime.exec), 
it acts as if it is running in a remote session (`Enter-PSSession`) (see [#3996](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3996)).

**In Windows 10 1607 *and* 1903:**
A locally started powershell.exe without Console acts as if it had a Console (just like run from cmd.exe) with regard to STDERR handling.
(No Exception is generated, instead all output on STDERR from child processes is passed through STDERR of powershell.exe)

Side Note: When using `Enter-PSSession` explicitly, PoSh behaves identically on 1607, 1809 and 1903.

One viable solution is to wrap all powershell.exe calls via a application that does CreateProcess with the 'CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE' flag and redirect stdout, as well as stderr to it's parent streams.
The [MSDN example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) can easily be modified to act as such a "proxy application".

Comment: thanks @mwallner. do you happen to know the bug/feature number by MS for this behavior change in 1903? I also confirmed the same problem on the same Windows versions...but I cannot tell if the fix was on Windows or powershell.

Comment: unfortunately not, I've ended up using a 'ConsoleExecWrapper' that is used in all of our Jenkins jobs to wrap powershell.exe and ensure it has a conhost on all Windows Job executor machines.